# How to guard the initialization of data to one thread?

Tags: c++, mutex, c++20, atomic, stdatomic

Using modern C++, what is the best way to have some shared memory that is initialized by one thread, the first to get to this point, and then read by many threads? It needs to be as lightweight as possible.

```
int *ptr = nullptr;

void parallel_work() {
    // this should only done by the first thread to this point
    ptr = init_ptr();

    // all threads read After ptr is set 
    do_with(ptr);
}


int main() {
    std::thread th0 { &parallel_work };
    std::thread th1 { &parallel_work };
    std::thread th2 { &parallel_work };
    parallel_work();
}
```

If it can help, I really want to avoid wrapping the whole read part of the code in a `mutex`.

PS: this is not the use case for `static` function variables, as I'll be creating many of these in the program's lifetime.

Comment: Make `ptr` a local static variable. Anyway it's not used outside the function.

Comment: @273K the code is a simplified example. As I said in my closing remark, I will be creating many of these.

Comment: "the first to get to this point" - main thread is the first to get to that point, so just initialize your `int* ptr` before launching other threads.

Comment: You didn't get it. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @pptaszni sorry how can you guarantee that the main thread gets there first?

Comment: Initialize it before starting the threads.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't.

Comment: @111111 Please explain your requirement. Are you going to initialize many ptrs at once or once by once? Can't believe such a high-reputated user can't clearly describe the task.

Comment: Nah forget my comment, from your example it looked like you can just initialize it before launching the threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::call_once` does exactly this.

```
int *ptr = nullptr;
std::once_flag flag;

void parallel_work() {
    std::call_once(&flag, []() {
        ptr = init_ptr();
    });

    do_with(ptr);
}
```

It even forces other threads to wait until `init_ptr` is done and it synchronizes to make sure they all see the initialized value of `ptr`.

Comment: So do all of the other threads wait whilst std::once is setting `ptr`?

Comment: @111111  yes, they wait. I think `static` (in the other answer) also makes them wait.

Comment: Hmmmm, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once is pretty poorly worded. Passive calls apparently return straight away and also apparently bock until the active call finishes.

Comment: @111111 you are right, it does seem poor. It works if you interpret "returns right away" as "doesn't call anything else" rather than "doesn't block"

Comment: no, I think it works if it DOES block the passive threads. By the time all threads get to `do_with()`, I need them all to have observed the initialisation of ptr.

Comment: @111111 that's what I said: *don't* interpret it as non-blocking. You could try it out, if you're not sure - make the function sleep for 1000ms or something like that

Comment: yep, it appears to block https://ideone.com/8m4V6j

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, make `ptr` a local static variable.

```
int* get_ptr() {
  static int *ptr = init_ptr();
  return ptr;
}

void parallel_work() {
  // all threads read After ptr is set 
  do_with(get_ptr());
}
```

Comment: I think they want to be able to do this multiple times though so a function static won't work

Comment: @Alan What to do multiple times? It's absolutely unclear.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear but I'd guess something like https://godbolt.org/z/968joYfnv (hopefully with more classes and fewer global variables)

Comment: Please re read my post. I am going to end up with lots of ptrs. It was a simplified example.

Comment: @Alan I don't see any traces of such behavior in the OP question. We should not guess or extend more than it is described.

Comment: @273K people can down-vote for any reason, it might not even have been the OP that down-voted. They did explicitly mention in their question that function statics wouldn't work for their usecase

Comment: The issue is these are created dynamically. I tried to explain my use case and explained how it was a simplified example. It is not possible for me to replicate complicated software in a way that distills the very question I am asking. Sometimes users need to accept that question comes with limitation greater than is apparent in the code sample.

Answer (score -1):

Scott Mayer's singleton will do. Just put the statc object inside a function:

```
result_t& single (){
    static result_t res{ /*initialization parameters*/};
    return res;
};
```

Compiler manages the initialization on 1st call of the ownin function, via a hidden `once_flag` object or similar magic.

Comment: I think they want to be able to do this multiple times though so a function static won't work

Comment: Sorry my example was simplified, I mentioned this in my closing remark. I will end up with lots of ptrs that need initialising in this manner.

Comment: Then go with user253751. You can elaborate by making structs or putting them in containers.